# Decode remote control codes through audio input

Tags: java, android

I am currently writing an Android app that functions as an internet radio. Part of the functionality of the app is that it is controllable via infrared remote. The infrared remote codes come in as analogue audio through the microphone port. If I record some of the signals and look at them in Audacity, it's very easy for me to see what each code is. For example, the following is 0111111010011001011111101000001 or 0x3F4CBF41. 
[image]
My question is how can I programmatically detect these signals when they come in and convert them to integer code numbers. I have looked into some packaged solutions like LIRC, but they're written in C and would be difficult to integrate. It also seems to me like native would be over kill to do such simple analysis. I also looked into libraries like musicg, but I couldn't find any easy way to convert the codes in real time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what information is missing here. Should I attach a sound file containing the data? So far my app does not record and save the data. It comes in as an analog signal through the microphone port. After it's processed the only output I expected was an integer number representing the remote code as I mentioned in the question. Could you be more specific about what is missing? As for the complexity, I spend a lot of time writing computer vision applications. I kind of assumed that this would be similar in complexity. Was I wrong?

Comment: @Xaver as someone who has developed proprietary solutions for a similar need I have to agree with the poster, the necessary information has been provided.  Your questions are curiosities only tangential to the question of the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems clear from your question that you are familiar with PWM and the method of reading the signal received from the IR receiver. As such, I have looked in to how you can use java to store the data in a method you can interpret as easily as your audacity window.

There are a couple methods in [javax.sound.sampled.spi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/spi/package-summary.html) That I think would help.

The first is [getAudioStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/spi/AudioFileReader.html#getAudioInputStream-java.io.InputStream-) in `AudioFileReader`.  This returns an `AudioStream` which has a few more methods which may prove useful.  The one I see as most handy for your purpose is [read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#read--) which returns the next byte in the stream. You can provide a byte array to read parts or even the whole stream in to as well if that is more convenient.

So now you have a list or array of bytes, and you can interpret them as high or low at regular intervals (because this is sampled audio, the time between each byte is constant) which is all you need for PWM decoding!

By finding an approximate endpoint, you can turn a byte pattern over time to a pattern of high/low durations. Since I know you can read that (demonstrated in your question) I will skip the pedantic conversion, but it is trivial to convert `hhhlhllhhhhhhlllhh` into a hexadecimal representation of the code.

TL;DR: Capture the stream, read each byte, convert via time, convert to binary.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've followed your advice and I'm definitely making progress. Right now what I understand is the way the frames seem to fluctuate a lot more than they do in Audacity. They bounce back and forth between positive and negative numbers several times in one pulse. Can you think of an explanation?

Comment: try changing your sample rate.

Comment: You might need to post-process the IR sensor data. Sample at a very high rate, then time average the sample to get a smooth signal. eg       t = 9/10 * t + 1/10 * t0

Comment: There's something I don't understand. The sample rate of the Audacity recording and of what I'm looking at in Java has to be the same. I'm currently just loading the PCM audio into Java. Am I missing something? Is Audacity lowering the sample rate for its visualization without telling me?

Comment: For anyone finding this now, the reason I was seeing strange audio data in Java was that it was outputting larger integer values as a series of multiple bytes which needed to be merged back into `int`s before processing.